Can I port forward in my second router connected to the primary one?
I am having a weird situation.
I have my ISP router and I don't have its password!
I can't login to 192.168.1.1 and configure port forwarding.
I have also one unused second router Asus.
I connected isprouter lan 1 -> internet port of asus and now I have a secondary network at home that works fine. I can connect devices with lan or wifi to asus router and they internet access.
Question:
If I port forward something in asus router, does that work correctly and I bypass having to change port-forwarding in the isp router itself ?
Example:
device with mac aa:bb is connected to AsusRouter via WIFI and has ip address 192.168.50.7
I want to port forward udp and tcp 6667. If I configure AsusRouter to port forward this, will it work even if ISPRouter doesn't have such a rule ?

You can often google the ISP's default username and password + the router may not be at 192.168.1.1 - the one my ISP Provides is 192.168.1.254, and I found this out by checking the default gateway on a directly connected machine.

My router is at 192.168.1.1 I can access the login page fine, just don't have pass. The password is set by isp workers, I have called them and they said have not written the password so none knows. The only option is to have them come over, factory reset router and give me the new password + set up internet settings again (they want to charge for this which I don't want and am looking for alternative way)

there is no alternative way - if you need port forwarding you need to do it on the first router

What kind of internet connection do you have, and what are the make and model of your routers?   I'm wondering if you can replace the ISP router with your router.

Your ISP advice sounds very suspect.   I'd be inclined to try again (at a different time of day) and see if you get the same advice a second time.  If you live in a country with decent consumer protection laws maybe you can compel them to help you at no charge to you under those laws - maybe you can even sweeten the deal by suggesting a forward replacement - no home visit required?

No, you cannot successfully port-forward from the Internet without configuring port forwarding on all the routers inline between your server and your public IP.
Imagine your house has a front door, and a bathroom door. Your Asus router is the bathroom door, and the ISP router is your front-door. you can't let people into the house by opening only the bathroom door.
You have a few options:

Contact the ISP and get the password, or perhaps you can have them configure the router.
Contact the ISP about putting your router into bridge mode, letting your ASUS router act as your gateway router
Use a VPN or SSH reverse tunnel service to enable remote inbound connections. This will cost money on a monthly cycle, since it will require external services. Its also by far the most complex way to do things, with a lot of moving parts and points for potential failures.


Thank you. That explains why I couldn't see my port forwarded using port checker online tools. I thought maybe my software was not listening but apparently I have to "port forward" the same port in the first router (ISPRouter) as well

I am interested to learn more about option 3, using a VPN. Can using a VPN allow me to do the port forwarding hm... ? I don't get it how it can help with that

Some commercial VPN services will rent you a public IP address that you can use as a reverse tunnel back into your network, basically like port forwarding. I can't recommend a specific service, but look for one that  offers public IPs. you connect your server to their VPN, and they route traffic they receive on that public IP through the tunnel to your server.
